# Automatic weight not working

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I was trying to make a simple rig with a Low Poly Character but something went wrong with the automatic weight when parenting because is not working. I tried several times and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Here's a video about the problem:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qr5aYQFVI9YdgK53J_SHHqquqFOVMl8r/view?usp=sharing

and the blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTvD5mM1S_ZZM0k6OYwKO_TiGR8K4aAA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: have you tried to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to assign automatic from bones and normalize all but I don't think its working

Comment: You should add screenshots to your question. The links to the blend file provided are private. Readers that might have the same problem looking for a solution will have no idea how your low poly character looks like, how the weight painting is done, and what went wrong, and if this Q is relevant to them. The question in the current state is not very helpful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually paint weights values of `0-1` in weight-paint mode. There is no easy way to go about it besides the automatic-weights assignment which you'd already stated as invalid for this scenario. Additionally, make sure that your mesh has no double (overlapping) vertices.